# Netbeans / php temporary disable hints

Tags: php, netbeans, hints

I am using Netbeans 8 with PHP.

Is there any way to disable the hints temporarily  - for example disable the "method too long" hint for the next method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147171/netbeans-7-4-introduces-10-lines-max-per-method-rule-where-does-this-rule-com

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic21108.html) forum post.

just select Tools - Options - Editor 
On the "Hints" tab choose Language: PHP

Now just uncheck the unwanted warning(s)

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding 
Ares.

P.S: If this answer helps, mark it accepted so the topic closes.

Comment: I want to disable the warning only for one method, for other (and especially new) methods in the same class the warning should stay.

Comment: I do NOT think that this is possible... You are trying to disable just for one particular method?? ... I find it hard to believe...