# A php function will work well if has more than 20 lines?

Tags: php, function, netbeans

I´m creating a function in php with netbeans, but it says:

> Method Length is 35 lines (20 allowed)

This will work well or I have to do a function with less than 20 lines?

Code:

```
function hasPrev($filterid) {
    switch ($filterid) {
        case 1:
            return false;
        case 10:
            return false;
        case 19:
            return false;
        case 28:
            return false;
        case 88:
            return false;
        case 148:
            return false;
        case 208:
            return false;
        case 238:
            return false;
        case 248:
            return false;
        case 258:
            return false;
        case 261:
            return false;
        case 264:
            return false;
        case 269:
            return false;
        case 274:
            return false;
        case 279:
            return false;
        case 284:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: that's completely subjective, not every method can be under 20 lines xD

Comment: So, it is supposed to work?

Comment: I think that is more of a coding style to improve code quality so that every function has exactly one purpose (single responsibility principle)

Comment: Even function with 1000 lines will work if it's written correctly.

Comment: have a look at [netbeans-7-4-introduces-10-lines-max-per-method-rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147171/netbeans-7-4-introduces-10-lines-max-per-method-rule-where-does-this-rule-com)

Comment: replace this spaghetti with `in_array`

Comment: as a note to your code - they all return false, you can chain case statements :)

Comment: No, if it is not any of that numbers it will return true

Comment: @AndoniDíezGuerra who was that last comment aimed at^^ all the above will still return true if you chain your cases or use `in_array()`

Comment: I think you are wrong, because it is returning the values that I expected

Comment: @AndoniDíezGuerra I mean [this](https://3v4l.org/Wu2r9) - can shorten your code this way

Comment: Consider this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147171/netbeans-7-4-introduces-10-lines-max-per-method-rule-where-does-this-rule-com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from menu Tools choose options then editor in hints tab checkbox too many Lines